# Is it enough to use flops to measure mobile GPU performance?

Tags: opengl-es, gpu

[Here, blog from arm](https://community.arm.com/graphics/b/blog/posts/flipping-the-flops---how-arm-measures-gpu-compute-performance) said use flops to measure the performance. But is it enough?

For example, in a game engine, lots of textures need to get sampled, can can decrease fps. Can flops tell the ability to sample textures?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good question and also complicated. It relates to a lot of topics in modern computer architecture. Therefore, it is hard to cover everything in a short answer. But I will try my best to answer the questions and hopefully point the OP some directions to follow.

Actually, for both CPU and GPU, or any kind of compute devices, GFLOPS is only part of the equation. 
GFLOPS measures the pure compute capability of the device in terms of the ALU (arithmetic logic unit) performance, which tells developers that how much computations can be done in a certain time. 
However, in modern computer architecture, memory performance is typically the real system bottleneck. Imagine that a typical compute task work flow is as follows (a very simplified version):

1. Read input data from the memory
2. Perform some computation and generate the output value
3. Store the output value back to the memory

GFLOPS only possibly measure the potential of a compute device to finish the step 2 (even for step 2, we still have a lot of other factors. For example, modern computers have multiple levels of cache to improve the data loading and storing performance, therefore, the data in step 2 are highly possible to be stored in some level of the cache memory).

To achieve good overall performance, we need good balance between memory system and compute ALUs. Therefore, there are a lot of theories behind high performance computing telling people how to achieve the best performance or how to design a computer system to achieve the best performance. One of the theory is the Roofline model: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~kubitron/cs252/handouts/papers/RooflineVyNoYellow.pdf

To answer your question related to graphics system, texture sampling is done in the texture memory hardware system inside a GPU core, which includes texture memory, texture cache, texture sampling units and so on. Therefore, the texture sampling mainly depends on the texture units.

But again, the modern computer system is complicated system. A lot of factors including ALU, memory system, cache, driver, shader compiler and so on will significantly affect the overall performance. To achieve better performance, we need to consider all these factors.